# Error in pig command

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, apache-pig, virtualization

I am working through some examples on a new hadoop/pig setup.
This, rather straightforward example code is baffling me..

```
A1 = load 'passwd' using PigStorage(':') as (f1:chararray,f2:chararray,f3:chararray,f4:chararray,f5:chararray,f6:chararray,f7:chararray);

G = group A1 by f7;

foreach G generate group, a.$2;
```

the last foreach on G is failing with the following error message -

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing.
Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "foreach "" at line 1, column 1.
```

Can someone pls be polite enough to point me what am i missing here ? or am i just being rusty here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the last line like this.

```
H = foreach G generate group, A1.$2;
DUMP H;
```

here **A1.$2** means you are trying to access f3 column, other option is

```
H = foreach G generate group, A1.f3;
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks, I believe the problems were around

1. not having a bag to assign the foreach G results to, So,

   foreach G generate....

would not work, but

```
H = foreach....
```

did.

2. using a instead of A1.
   I used an unknown variable "a" instead of the right bag that I should have been referring to, A1.

so, the correct command that worked for me -

```
H = foreach G generate group, A1.f1;
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm really sorry to not explain the root cause of the problem instead of just posted the solution. Now you understood the problem and explained it clearly +1.